# Можно ли монитор с разрешение 4К или 2К перевести в FullHD?

Tags: монитор

Я хочу купить монитор для работы (фронтенд-разрабочик) с потенциалом на будущее. Бюджет до 17000.
Встал перед выбором между монитором AOC G2590FX 24.5" со 144Гц (для игр, только через DisplayPort), TN-матрицей (-) или монитором Philips 245E1S 23.8" со 75Гц (- для игр), IPS (+), QuadHD.
Могу ли я в случае необходимости как-нибудь перевести изображение из QuadHD в FullHD (ну то есть увеличить в два раза пиксель)?
А если возьму монитор с разрешением 4К, то смогу ли я перевести 4К разрешение в FullHD?
Мне это может понадобится для моей работы, верстать сайты из шаблонов идеально по пикселям.
Если это сделать невозможно, то посоветуйте тогда годный монитор до 17 000 (чем дешевле, тем лучше) игровой (чтоб от 144Гц) или с высоким ppi. Я буду подключать по HDMI. Ещё желательно, чтоб был DisplayPort.
Спасибо за внимание.

Comment: С нормальными мониторами никаких проблем (осталось объяснить софту (ОС) в каком разрешении вы хотите работать с монитором (по умолчанию обычно софт выбирает максимум из предоставляемого монитором (в начале работы софт запрашивает монитор и получает от него список доступных форматов)))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

По идее мониторы поддерживают разрешения меньше максимального, так что я считаю, что переключить на 1920*1080 можно. И это будет вполне хорошо выглядеть если родное соотношение сторон 16:9, а не какое-то другое.

У меня, например, монитор 1920*1200 - и даже его я могу переключить в 1920*1080 или даже 1024*768, при этом либо изображение станет растянутым, либо по краям появятся чёрные полосы.

На хабре есть [целая статья](https://habr.com/ru/post/508824/), почему надо брать 4К монитор, хотя лично я с ней скорее не согласен. Но вот с тем, что множитель должен быть целый, я бы согласился.

> Мне это может понадобится для моей работы, верстать сайты из шаблонов идеально по пикселям.

А вот тут интересный момент. Во-первых, браузер работает обычно не с размером монитора, а с размером окна. <s>Во-вторых, у меня есть подозрение, что в него может просочится число экранных пикселей на виртуальный (хотя я не проверял).</s> Проверил - вроде бы нет. Ну а в-третьих, есть же эмуляция разрешения.

Comment: Насчёт просачивания. Если десктопный 4К экран отображает 1920, значит у всей оси стоит 1920, и просачиваться ничего не будет (единица). Браузер думает, что разрешение родное. Просто 4 пикселя монитора чётко отображают 1 пиксель оси.